# Social networking integration with OAuth in iPhone

Tags: iphone, oauth

I am new to iPhone programming.

Can someone please explain me what is OAuth and how it can be used in social networking integration?

How many social networking sites provide an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use - [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/)

Comment: If my ans is useful ans solve your problem then you should make it right ans by selecting right box.

Comment: hi love chetu sharekit is based on oauth

Comment: hi all
i got the basic understanding of oauth
the link are:

 http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-15#section-1

thanks

Comment: @prashant If that answered your question, perhaps you should post that as an answer (with a bit more than explanation than just the link) rather than a comment on another answer.