# OAuth integration in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, oauth-2.0

I have one problem regarding OAuth integration in iPhone App.

Can anyone help me how to integrate [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net) with [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com) in iPhone ?

I have referred so many sites about OAuth but I haven't got satisfied answer yet. I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027304/social-networking-integration-with-oauth-in-iphone) of [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). There is one good option about [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/). But my client wants only OAuth 2.0.

I downloaded [framework](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/obj-c/OAuthConsumer/) from google code. I integrated it in my application. But How to use it ? Without guidance I can't implement it in proper way.

I have got stuck between my application and 0Auth 2.0 since last **3 days**. Please can anyone give me idea or demo project or any another tutorial ?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than implement OAuth for Facebook, make use of the Facebook iOS SDK which makes handling Facebook Auth and Requests much easier. You can read about it and download it here... http://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already implemented facebook iOS SDK. But as I said my client wants only OAuth 2.0.

Comment: That's a shame, there's a few OAuth2 options here which may be of use... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374570/whats-the-best-ios-oauth2-framework

Answer (score 2):

I just done a research

This [post](http://davidquail.com/2009/12/07/oauth-authorization-callback-on-the-iphone-with-webview/) will really help you

Also please look at the below posts

[iphone-facebook-oauth2-graph-api](http://www.capturetheconversation.com/best-practices/iphone-facebook-oauth2-graph-api)

[OAuth and Facebook iPhone SDK](http://alohacocoa.com/)

Comment: I have implemented it. It works fine. Thank you but now the problem is How to terminate session ? I can fetch data from graph.facebook.com with access token. But when I start my application second time it doesn't ask about login. Can you give me your contact email ? So I can send you my project.

Comment: And can you suggest it for twitter ?

Comment: my email id is ramshadram90@gmail.com .. if my solution works, u can accept my answer and expecting one up-vote too :) for integrating twitter, please download the sample from here https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone  About your new question "when I start my application second time it doesn't ask about login " please start the topic as separate thread in stack overflow and give me the issue details or the question link.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The framework you mentioned in your post is not for OAuth 2, but for OAuth 1.0a.

You can try the [OAuth2Client](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client) we developed for talking to the SoundCloud API. It's build against draft 10 of the spec. I'm not sure which one is used by Facebook. Unfortunately the spec is not final yet and over the years different services adopted different drafts of the spec.

If you're able to argue with your client I'd try to convince him to let you go with the [official iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). This gives you many benefits like automatic token refresh, single sign on via the official app & much more.